# sort nested defaultdict within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested, defaultdict

Having trouble wrapping my head around how to order this list which consists of nested defaultdicts. I was able to sort by 'registration' key and the 'classes' value with this;

```
sorted(dict1.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Which produced;

`[('registration', {'count': 11, 'classes': Counter({'class1': 5, 'class2': 5, 'class3': 1}), 'date': defaultdict(<function date_record at 0x7fc173646500>, {datetime.date(2016, 6, 7): {'count': 1, 'hour': Counter({16: 1})}, datetime.date(2016, 6, 6): {'count': 10, 'hour': Counter({16: 5, 14: 2, 8: 1, 10: 1, 12: 1})}})})]`

However now I'm trying to sort by 'date' which is a nested defaultdict. I'm trying to order by the date chronologically (from - to) and then finally, order the 'hour' Counter() chronologically (for reference; 8 = 8am, and 16 = 4pm).

So the above defaultdict should look like this;

`[('registration', {'count': 11, 'classes': Counter({'class1': 5, 'class2': 5, 'class3': 1}), 'date': defaultdict(<function date_record at 0x7fc173646500>, {datetime.date(2016, 6, 6): {'count': 10, 'hour': Counter({16: 5, 14: 2, 12: 1, 10: 1, 8: 1})}, datetime.date(2016, 6, 7): {'count': 1, 'hour': Counter({16: 1, 14: 4})}})})]`

I'm just having trouble figuring out how to access the defaultdict. Any guidance on how I can access it within a sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key`parameter to sort or sorted can be any callable. This callable should return objects taht are directly comparable with Python's `==` and `<=` operators. There is no need for the object passed as `key` to be the callable returned by `itemgetter` or some other complicated construct.

There is no need for it to be a short - one expression function - that can be in a lambda as well.

So, just define a function, let it have the size it has to - to retrieve the attributes you want to compare on. If there are more than one value, return a sequence with those values. Pass this function on the `key` named parameter to `sort`.

I am not certain if I can figure out how you ant to order your keys/values inside your `date` nested dir, but it could be something along:

```
def sort_key(item):
    dates = list(item["date"].items())
    # the key in the lambda bellow will get 
    # tuples with the datetime and subdictionary for each date:

    dates.sort(key=lambda inner_date: (inner_date[0], sorted(inner_date[1]["hour"].keys())
    return dates
```

Note that you need the inner sorting in rder to have your keys respecting the "hour" values as well - I did that by making each key on the sort of each "date" of each of your list items return a tuple where the first element is the "date" itself used as key, the second, a sorted list of the values showing up in the counter (but not the count for each value)  .

If this secondary key is too complex to fit in a lambda, just create another function for it. These functions will only be called once for each item in the outer list you are sorting, so your performance should still be ok.

Comment: Hey jsbueno, thanks for your response. I tried the above and i think there's a problem grabbing the 'date' key `dates = list(item["date"].iteritems())
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` (I tried with .items same thing). For some reason it's not recognizing the key value and thinking it's a list indice. Any idea on how I can get the key?

Comment: I played around with it a bit more and did this `dates = list(item[0][1]["date"].items())` but as you imagine, this only gets the first result only. I think I need a lambda function to iterate over the [0][1] but haven't been able to figure it out with the examples I've seen.

Comment: Sort've figured it out, using a for loop and then sorting it there. Thanks for the help/guidance!